# WSO2 API + SSO - Passive mode and anonymous store access

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 API Manager 2.6 with SSO enabled. In the site.json in the store jaggery app we have configured the following parameters:

```
"ssoConfiguration" : {
"enabled" : "true",
"issuer" : "API_STORE",
"identityProviderURL" : "https://identity.it/samlsso",
"keyStorePassword" : "",
"identityAlias" : "",
"responseSigningEnabled":"true",
"assertionSigningEnabled":"true",
"verifyAssertionValidityPeriod":"true",
"timestampSkewInSeconds":"300",
"audienceRestrictionsEnabled":"true",
"keyStoreName" :"",
"passive" : "true",
...
```

}

When we navigate through the store site as guest user (without logging in), the store redirects, silently,  all the requests to https://identity.it/samlsso (without asking the credentials) before reaching the destination page.
How can we enable a guest user to navigate through the store web site without redirecting all the requests to the identity?

In version 2.1, to get it we have configured the **passive parameter to false**, in this version it doesn't work because it redirects all the requests to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After a long searching I have found this statement

```
if ((!session.get("hasTriedSSO") || Boolean(user)) && site.ssoConfiguration.enabled == "true" && site.ssoConfiguration.passive == "true") {
  jagg.includeBlock("sso/filter", {});
}
```

I think this condition is not right. Because It should include block only when `site.ssoConfiguration.passive` is **false** not **true**.

It is located in

```
repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\site\blocks\api\api-info\block.jag
repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\store\site\blocks\site\pages\list-apis.jag
```

I've change this `site.ssoConfiguration.enabled == "false"` and it worked for me. But I'm not sure that is the best solution.